# First line after mdframed has no indent

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, mdframed

First line after mdframed has no indent.
Then everything is normal.
How to fit it?
[image]

Main tex file

```
\documentclass[draft, twoside, 10pt, openright]{extbook}
\usepackage[a5paper, outer=15mm,inner=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=15mm,footskip=1.5em,headsep=4pt,headheight=1em]{geometry}
% \usepackage[a5paper, outer=36mm,inner=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=28mm,footskip=1.5em,headsep=4pt,headheight=1em]{geometry}
\usepackage[russian,ukrainian]{babel}    %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}



\def\sectiontitlename{РОЗДІЛ}
\def\parttitlename{Частина}

% =============================================================================
%
%                           НАЛАШТОВУЄМО ШРИФТИ
%
% =============================================================================


\setstretch {1.05}
% \defaultfontfeatures[Slopes]{LetterSpace=8.0}
\defaultfontfeatures[Ropa Mix PTT]{StylisticSet=4}
\setsansfont{Ropa Mix PTT}    % Sans font

% \setmainfont[ItalicFont={Ropa Mix PTT}]{Theano Old Style}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={Ropa Mix PTT}]{Trivia Humanist Regular}
         
\newfontfamily{\tobyfnt}{Tobi Dirt Black}
\newfontfamily{\toprule}{Tobi Dirt Dingbat Shape}
\newfontfamily{\secfnt}{Tobi Light Dirt Rough}
\newfontfamily{\notefnt}{Ropa Mix PTT}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
% \newfontfamily{\remfnt}{Rounded Elegance}

% \newfontfamily{\regenfont}{regen}

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                          ТЕПЕР СТВОРИМО НОВІ РОЗМІРИ 
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand\YUGE{\fontsize{48}{80}\selectfont} 
\newcommand\REMSIZE{\fontsize{68}{80}\selectfont} 


% ---------------------------------------------------------------
%                  Modification TOP rule
% ---------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand\headrule{%
  \vspace{-1.1em}
  \hrulefill {\toprule\raisebox{-4pt}{\Huge k}\hrulefill}
}

% ------------------ END top rule dofication ---------------------


\fancypagestyle{headings}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{} % except the center
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand\headrule{}
}


% --------------- Формат для оглавлений ------------------------
\titleformat{\part}
{\centering}
{\tobyfnt\YUGE\partname \space \thepart}
{1em}
{\thispagestyle{empty}}


\titleformat{\section}
{\centering\secfnt\large}
{\sectiontitlename\space\thesection}
{0.6em}
{}
[]

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\centering}
{}
{0.5em}
{}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*1}{*1}

% ==================================================================
%
%                  СТВОРИМО КІЛЬКА СТИЛІВ ДЛЯ MDFRAMED
%
% ==================================================================

% -----------------------
%     Ремарки
% -----------------------
\mdfdefinestyle{rem}{
  linewidth=0.2pt,
  backgroundcolor=black!7,
  linecolor=black!100,
  outermargin=20mm,
  innermargin=20mm,
  innerrightmargin=0.5em,
  innerleftmargin=0.5em,
  font={\sf},
  roundcorner=1em
}

% -----------------------
%     Вірші
% -----------------------

\mdfdefinestyle{verse}{
  linewidth=0pt,
  linecolor=black!0,
  innerleftmargin=8em,
  startinnercode={\baselineskip=10pt},
  font={\sf}
}

\mdfdefinestyle{bible}{
  topline=false,%
  rightline=false,%
  bottomline=false,%
  linewidth=0.8pt,
  linecolor=black!100,
  outermargin=0em,
  innermargin=1em,
  innerrightmargin=1em,
  innerleftmargin=1em,
  font={\sf},
}


% ---------------- Основная информация книги ----------------------



% ================ Настройка некоторых параметров =================|
%\sloppy %----------------------------- Красивое формирование строк|
\tolerance=600
\parindent=1.8em %-----------------------------Отступ первой строки|
% -----------------------------------------------------------------|

\emergencystretch=2pt
\hfuzz=0.9pt
%\doublehyphendemerits=9000000
% ---------------- Двухколоночное формирование текста -------------

\interlinepenalty=5
\raggedbottom
\clubpenalty=10000  
\widowpenalty=10000
%\linespread{0.93}

\ULdepth = 0.2em

%==================================================================
%                                                                 |
%                   BEGIN OF DOCUMENT                             |
%                                                                 |
%==================================================================
\newcommand{\remtxt}{
  \begin{mdframed}[style=rem]
    В цьому місці є пробіл, який потрібно буде
    заповнити пізніше, оскільки є тільки нариси
  \end{mdframed}
}

\newcommand{\versetxt}[1]{
\begin{mdframed}[style=verse]
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setstretch{1.05}
\hsadabox 1em #1
\end{mdframed} 
}


\makeatletter

\let\booktitle\@title
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}%clear all
\fancyhead{}%clear all
\fancyhead[LO, RE]{\notefnt\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\notefnt\MakeUppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\notefnt\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}

\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{
\vspace*{3pc}
}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\parttitlename\space \thepart}{}
}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{\sectiontitlename\space \thesection}{}
}

\makeatletter

\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\newpage
\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\section}{\par\penalty100}% Inserting a \par here and allowing page breaks!
{}{}
\makeatother

 \counterwithin*{section}{part}
\let\nonumberclearpage\clearpage
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{\nonumberclearpage\thispagestyle{empty}}

\begin{document}


\author{Ігор Юхименко}
\title{Краплини дощу}
\newcommand{\speek}{—\enspace}
% \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\counterwithin*{footnote}{part}

% ================ Main content of book ========================

\includepdf[pages=-]{design/Internalcover.pdf}

%=BEGIN=

%\setcounter{part}{1}
\input{Part1.tex}
\input{Part2.tex}
% \input{Kira_Part1.tex}
% \input{Part3.tex}
% \input{Part4.tex}

 
%=END=

% =================================================================

\end{document}
```

Fragment with text

```
Раптом почув слова знайомої пісні:\par
\begin{mdframed}[style=verse]
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setstretch{1.05}
\par
Вся земля так довго на цей день чекала:\par
Коли злине з неба теплий літій дощ,\par
Коли Сонце правди порозгонить хмари,\par
Коли пісню щастя заспіває хтось...\par
\end{mdframed}
Це християнська пісня й тітка її частенько слухала. Так як робити мені зараз нічого, я вирішив підійти ближче й подивитися на виконавців.\par
Їх виявилося всього двоє: хлопець на дівчина. Він грав на синтезаторі, а вона співала:\par
```

Comment: your example is way too long for a test, but try what happens if you add an empty line after the \end{mdframed}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, It worked.